# Updating Layout of a row in ListView when OnClick event is called

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-canvas, onclicklistener

I have a ListView in which there is a TextView and a custom view in which I am drawing a rectangle. I want a functionality that when a row of ListView is clicked, the rectangle should become bigger but other row's rectangle should remain in its previous shape.

So first I am increasing width and height of layout and then trying to increase the rectangle size after that but although my onDraw() method is called when I am clicking the listener but size of rectangle is not increasing.

Also my onDraw() method of DrawView is called infinitely even though I am clicking only once
Can anyone help me out.

DrawView.java, which is used for making making rectangle

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    public int x=-1;   // this variable will tell 

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);            
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        Log.e("Ronak","onDraw  "+x);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 300, 200, paint );
        if(x>=0)  //this method is not called for first view but is called for onClickListener
        {
            increase(canvas);
        }


    }

    private void increase(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.e("Ronak","Increase");
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 700, 800, paint );

    }




}
```

My getView() function for custom ListView

```
        public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_item,null);
                        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
                           TextView t= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        holder.textview = t;
                        holder.ll=layout;
                        final DrawView abc = (DrawView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawview);
                        holder.drawview=abc;
                        Log.e("Ronak","reached here3");            
                        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textview.setText(mData.get(position));


        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(c, "Clicked on="+position, 2).show();
             ViewHolder mH = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams pp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500,400);
             mH.ll.setLayoutParams(pp);
             DrawView dd=mH.drawview;
             dd.x=position;
             dd.invalidate();
                }
        });

        return convertView;



    }

     static class ViewHolder {
            public DrawView drawview;
            public TextView textview;
            public LinearLayout ll;
        }
```

and my layout file for each row of ListView

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <com.krish.horizontalscrollview.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/drawview"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >
    </com.krish.horizontalscrollview.DrawView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My ListView class

```
    public class CenterLockHorizontalScrollview extends HorizontalScrollView {
    Context context;
    int prevIndex = 0;

    public CenterLockHorizontalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        this.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);

    }



    public void setAdapter(Context context, CustomListAdapter mAdapter) {

        try {
            fillViewWithAdapter(mAdapter);
        } catch (ZeroChildException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void fillViewWithAdapter(CustomListAdapter mAdapter)
            throws ZeroChildException {
        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
            throw new ZeroChildException(
                    "CenterLockHorizontalScrollView must have one child");
        }
        if (getChildCount() == 0 || mAdapter == null)
            return;

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);

        //parent.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            parent.addView(mAdapter.getView(i, null, parent));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you store a String list in mData. Make a class with members mData and mIsSelected (boolean) and pass an object of this class in the adapter. In onClick() check whether the row is already selected, invert the value of mIsSelected and perform the required operation at end call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Thanks, for the answer but my problem is rectangle size is not increasing when I am clicking on row in ListView

Comment: Continuing the previous comment, even though when I am clicking it is going into increase() method but the bigger rectangle is not showing on canvas

Comment: @user3265443 Do you call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter and `invalidate` on the ListView itself?

Comment: @AleksG Very sorry but I am not getting you. Can you please explain what you want to say

Comment: @user3265443 After you process changes in the list item layout, call method `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter and `invalidate` on the actual ListView - I think it's pretty obvious

Comment: My ListView is basically a extended class of HorizontalScrollView, so can you please tell me where in my code I have to include these two methods.

I have also included my HorizontalScrollView class. Can you please tell me how to do

Comment: @AleksG
But when I will call invalidate() on a ListView object, don't it change the view of all the rows of ListView

Comment: @user3265443 It very well may - but you are controlling it.  Your getView will be called for all rows - you need to know what to return based on your data (i.e. which rows are expanded and which are not)

Comment: @AleksG My adapter and listView objects is in MainActivity class, so how to access these elements from Adapter class(getView method) , where I am attaching the listener

Comment: @user3265443 Your listener should be in the adapter something like view.setOnClickListener( new onClick(View view) { ...(Invert mIsSelected and set the desired size then call notifyDataSetChanged()) ...});